# Accepting EULA for a quiet install of EXE file

Tags: c#, exe, eula

I am working on packaging up some installers for internal use. I have the uninstall working fine with a passive switch.

As for installation, the MSI's that do not have an EULA work perfectly with the passive switch showing progress.

The EXE's that contain an EULA are the problem.

I am trying to find a way to accept the EULA without user input - note I do not have access to changing the public properties of the EXE's to set the ACCEPTEULA=1

the base I am working with right now is...

```
start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
start.CreateNoWindow = true;
start.Arguments = s.args; //curent argument /qn
start.FileName = tempDir + "/" + s.executable;
start.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

While this code works perfectly fine with the msi's it does not work with the exe's as they all contain EULAs.

Comment: Go ahead and add your answer as a real answer to the question rather then edited into the question.

Comment: I cant for another 8 hours, if you want to add it I will mark your answer as correct. as I do not have enough rep.

Comment: Weird, I didn't know it took rep to answer your own question.

Comment: yea aparently 10 rep....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using an exe you need to preface `/qn` with `/v` making it:

```
setup.exe /v/qn
```

Comment: and I can mark your answr but need 15 rep to upvote you, sorry no upvote today lol